# Loosing current values API Keys stored in environment variable in Postman

Tags: postman

I have stored my API keys as environment variables in Postman. After logging into my API, a script reads fields and sets current values using `pm.environment.set('api-key-token', data.api_key)`.

The issue/inconvenience I am having is every time I change a Query param, I lose my API key current value. I thought the current values are only lost when you log out of your postman. Is this behavior normal?

Comment: Are you sure that you've already see the key-value of `api-key-token` in Environment variables window?

Comment: Yes, because I can access APIs. The issue occurs when I change a Query param; the current value will be lost, and I will have to log in to generate another API key.   Otherwise, it works well.